# Mixing hline and axhline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know I can use `hlines` to draw lines in data coordinates (e.g. from 2.5 to 5) as well as `axhline` to draw lines in axis coordinates (e.g. from 0, i.e. left border of plot, to 1, the right border).

Is there a way to draw a line mixing these two? In particular, I want to draw a line which starts at the left edge of the plot (0 in axis coordinates) regardless of any changes of xlim, but which ends at some fixed x value.

I tried

```
ax.plot([-np.inf, x], [y, y])
```

but this does not work.

Comment: While not practical, we could convert the data coordinate `x` in ax coordinate and use `axhline(0, x_transformed, ...)`. That would break every time you change the limits or zoom, too.

Comment: Right, I thought of that, too. But like you say, it doesn't really help if the axis limits are changed afterwards.

Comment: It depends on whether you update the limits yourself, in which case you can adjust the `axhline` in the same function call, or if you use autoscaling. Not ideal indeed. Alternatively, a callback that does `line.set_xdata([ax.get_xlim[0], x])` where `line, = ax.plot([], [])` every time the graph changes its limits.

Comment: I know you would prefer to draw the half-infinite line once and for all, it's more elegant, but that workaround should work and `plot` is definitely cleaner than `axhline` or `axvspan`. Otherwise, an even more silly hack: `ax.plot([-1e20, x], [y, y])`. The callback solution feels less dirty though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution based on the callback. We create the artist that will represent our left infinite line **without providing coordinates** because those will be filled automatically when the x-limits are changed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
half_line, = ax.plot([], [], color="black", linestyle="--")

def update_half_line_when_xlims_change(ax):
    """Ensures that the half line always goes from -infinity to the chosen x,
       regardless of zooming/panning/limits changes."""

    # Hardcoded parameters.
    xmax = 0
    y = -1

    # Fetch the current left limit.
    xmin, _ = ax.get_xlim()
    half_line.set_xdata((xmin, xmax))
    half_line.set_ydata((y, y))

ax.callbacks.connect("xlim_changed", update_half_line_when_xlims_change)

# Some dummy data.
X = np.linspace(-1, +1, 100)
Y1 = X**2
Y2 = np.sin(X*4)
Y3 = np.log(abs(X)+0.5)
for Y in (Y1, Y2, Y3):
    ax.plot(X, Y)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great. I wrapped it in a function and it works like a charm. The only problem I see is that the line doesn't appear if the xlim doesn't change after calling it. This can easily be fixed by simply running the called once manually. Thanks!

Comment: @cheersmate Glad it works. That gave me an occasion to learn about callbacks!